# PHP - How to combine three or more classes that each depend on each other?

Tags: php, class, oop

I have three classes:

1. **Database**
2. **User**
3. **Page**

Each does as it implies.

So, both **User** and **Page** need to connect to the database to get their data (User info, page content) - They both get access to the database via dependency injection from **Database**, and that's perfectly fine. However, **Page** *also* needs to display data gotten by **User**.

This becomes problematic because if I were inject **User** into **Page**, wouldn't that technically prompt **Page** to have **TWO** instances of the database, both it's own and the one exists in **User**? That's not good practice, correct?

From I can gather, 'extending' is not the proper solution in this case either. **Page** is not directly related to **User**, so they needn't become one.

So, I have two questions:

1. Would it be 'proper' to channel the database object injected into **User** to **Page** by injecting **User** into **Page**?
2. And, if not, what's the proper way to do this?

Comment: Could you extend the parent class?

Comment: If you initialize a `Database` object, you can pass that to the constructor of the `User` object. When you create a second `User` you can pass the same database object. When you create a `Page` object... you can pass the same `Database` object. Since it's the same object you only have one instance of it that many other objects hold references to.

Comment: @NathanielFord You mean I should pass the object injected into **User** into **Page**? The issue is that both **Page** and **User** is using the Database object, and **Page** is using **User**.

Comment: @SuperCat See below for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have some misapprehension about how references work. Let us say I create a database object:

```
class Database {
  function talkToDb(){
    //does some database stuff
  }
}
```

Now, lets say I want to have a `User` class that accesses a `Database` object - presumably for reading and writing to a persistence layer:

```
class User {
  persistence = null; //This 'points' to a database object that is injected on object instantiation.
  function __construct(Database $db) {
    $this->persistence = db;
  }
}
```

To create a `User` you would do the following, somewhere in code:

```
$db = new Database();
$aUser = new User($db);
$bUser = new User($db);
```

At this juncture `$aUser` and `$bUser` are using the *same* `Database` object. Lets talk about `Page`: it's instantiation is eerily similar to `User`:

```
class Page {
  $persistence = null;
  $someUser = null;

  function __construct(Database $db, User $user) {
    $this->persistence = $db;
    $this->someUser = $user;
  }
}
```

You'd then create - again, somewhere else in code - the `Page` class. Like so:

```
$db = new Database();
$aUser = new User($db);
$aPage = new Page($db, $aUser);
```

At this juncture, the *object fields* in both `$aUser` and `$aPage` are *pointing* to the **same** `Database` object: the one *named* `$db` (at least, it is named that in the scope in which we create it above). `$aPage` *also* holds a *reference* to `$aUser`. Because it has two references - one to the user and one to the database - it could *in theory* access that *same* database objects two ways:

```
class Page {
  ... //construct everything as above

  function accessExample() {
    //The following two lines call the exact same function on the exact same object
    $this->persistance->talkToDb();
    $this->someUser->persistance->talkToDb();
  }
}
```

Remember: when you 'inject' an object into two other objects, you're not copying that object, you're *simply copying the reference to the object*. It is appropriate for many objects to hold copies of the same reference.

The fact that you *can* get to the database either way doesn't mean you should. You can mask the `User`'s database from `Page` by making it private. That said, not doing so is only a matter of code cleanliness: you still *can*.

Note that it is *entirely inappropriate* to 'extend' either `Page` or `User` from one another or from the `Database`. An extended class is really a 'subset' or a 'more specific form' of the previous. A `User` is not a special form of a `Database`: a `MySqlDatabase` *is*. Rather, we know that a `User` needs to have a database it can 'persist' it's state to. This is why we provide it with a 'reference' to some `Database` object. We should provide the same reference to all such objects that require access to that same `Database`. The fact that many objects may hold a reference to the same database object is immaterial: why would this cause a problem?

(Caveat emptor: I'm not actually running the above code, so there may be minor bugs.)

Comment: Great write up.  Extending you're train of thought a little further, at the point that you have to pass a db reference to a bunch of objects, do you know of any reason to not just use a singleton pattern and a static db class?

Comment: Thanks! When and how to use singletons is highly controversial. I avoid it on the premise they are harder to test, and end up often binding you in unexpected ways. I do think it's a separate question, though, from what's being asked above: really I think you should leave this to a framework to handle (at least for the case of persistence) on the principle that a mature framework has thought about the impact *a lot more* than you ever will.

Answer (score 0):

Use a constructor in the database class and set it to a class property.
Assume its available in both user and page classes as you extend our from it.

```
<?php
class Database
{

}
class MySql extends Database
{
    private $sDbName      = '';
    private $sUsername    = '';
    private $sPassword    = '';
    private $sHost        = '';
    private $oConnection  = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->oConnection = new PDO( 
            'mysql:host=' 
            . $this->sHost 
            . ';dbname=' 
            . $this->sDbName, 
            $this->sUsername, 
            $this->sPassword 
            );
    }
    public function getDb()
    {
        return $this->oConnection;
    }
}

class User extends MySql
{

}
class Page extends User
{

}

$oPage = new Page;
var_dump( $oPage->getDb() );
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's proper to 'connect' **User** to **MySql**, and **Page** to **User**? Quite often I see that you should not extend classes unless they are directly related, Eg **class Nurse extends Medical**, not **class Christmas extends Spoon**.

Comment: Just as an example, one of the leading frameworks, Zend has a depth of 10-20-30 files extending from one another. It's more about usability/doing what you desire in the most efficient manner than theory.

Comment: This doesn't sound right at all. In general, a user is not a specialisation of a database, and a page is not a specialisation of a user or a database.

Comment: Except in this case the O/P is creating the classes directly from database tables.